# What are the advantages of sequences in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sequence

I upgraded my SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2012, and I had noticed a new feature was added: `Sequence`.

I don't know the reason of adding sequences when there is an `identity` property.

Can someone elaborate on what this feature is useful for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some examples

A sequence:

- allows you know the new number before you actually write to the table
  Example: how to get the IDENTITY value in a BEFORE TRIGGER
- one sequence can be used for more then one table
  A.k.a get a value that will be unique across many tables without supertype/subtype

Answer (score -2):

> Can someone elaborate on what this feature is useful for?

Generating sequences, is that not obvious?

Stuff like account numbers, order numbers, order numbers - that may not even be used as identity as in identity column.